# Form/Windows/Passport authentication vs Authentication Filter in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: .net, authentication, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

Why we need Authentication Filters if we already having Form/Windows/Passport Authentication in .NET.

[1) Types of authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-types-of-authentication-in-ASP-NET-MVC-5)

[2) Authentication Filters in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/filters-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-0-part-twelve/)

I'm know both are used to authenticate the user but

- Why we need both?
- Can we use both? If Yes, How it will work?

Tired Google but didn't got proper solution.

Comment: So you can execute additional code during the authentication process. Refer [this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters) for an example